# How to change level of all Log4J 1.x loggers?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I want to be able to programmatically set the logging level for all loggers.
This works:

```
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class);
    LogManager.getLogger(Example.class).setLevel(Level.FATAL);
    log.debug("Should not see!");
    LogManager.getLogger(Example.class).setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    log.debug("Should see!");
```

However this does not:

```
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class);
    LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.FATAL);
    log.debug("Should not see!");
    LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
    log.debug("Should see!");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the logger names from `LogManager.getCurrentLoggers()` and then set the `LogManager.getLogger("<name from loop>").setLevel(Level.FATAL)`; using loop.

When you are getting  `LogManager.getRootLogger()` gets the root level logger. It is not going to affect all the individual configuration.